# React-bootstrap and dark UI

Tags: reactjs, background-color, react-bootstrap

I'm new to reactjs. I'm trying to change the background colour using normal CSS for my react webapp but it doesn't change when I use react-bootstrap. Is there a way to do it through react-bootstrap ?

I included react-bootstrap through

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

in my index.js file created with create-react-app template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal with third party CSS libraries is that they always create conflicts with our CSS file. To remove this conflict either use `!important` in your styling (less appreciated) or try unsettling the background colour and re-setting it,

```
background-color: unset;
background-color: #000;
```

Do mind the order of these 2 lines

Comment: !important method worked. I'm going with that since its a small project. Thank you!